# css selector for html5 tag "Contenteditable"

Tags: html, css

How can I use css selector for contenteditable="true"

```
<div id="1" name="1" contentEditable="true"></div>
```

Comment: `contentEditable` is not a "tag", it's an **attribute**.

Comment: I shake my head in disbelief that someone down marked you. It is (a) a very good question, (b) came straight to the top of the google search, and (c) not a duplicate as he isn't asking how to style it, and (d) @user663031, it's ABOUT a tag whgich is clearly what OP means. The complaints about the elitist smack happy stackoverflow old guard are piling in and unless SO acts, this will keep driving people on to other sites.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use a [CSS attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors):

```
div[contenteditable="true"] {
    background: red;
}
```

In English, this means: *"Find all divs which have an attribute of contenteditable with its value set to true."* In the above example, we find all div elements that are contenteditables and give them a red background.

Answer (score 3):

Specify html selector, then in square brackets desired attribute and its value

```
div[contentEditable="true"]
```

Comment: `contentEditable=""` also makes the element editable, so the `="true"` is not correct. Also, the `div` part is unnecessary and possibly undesirable.

Comment: that would check for existence of atribute, whether it is present or not, regardless of its value

Answer (score 1):

You can select any type of attribute with the [css selector](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp) for attributes, just use `[atttributeName]`.

Comment: Contenteditable isn't a boolean attribute. This would also match `contenteditable="false"`