# Does HTML contenteditable attribute require a =true for it to work? Why does it work without it even though it's not a boolean attribute?

Tags: html, css, contenteditable

Does HTML contenteditable attribute require a `=true` for it to work? Why does it work without it even though it's not a boolean attribute?

The comment on this answer states that "Contenteditable isn't a boolean attribute.":

https://stackoverflow.com/a/45128348/1634905

For example if I have the following code:

`<p contenteditable placeholder="Website">www.example.com</p>`

this seems to work perfectly fine and the tag is editable even though I have not specified `=true`

Another thing I have noticed is that if I don't specify `=true`, then targeting it with CSS only works with:

`[contenteditable]` and not `[contenteditable="true"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't need a value and empty means true.

> The attribute must take one of the following values:
> true or an empty string, which indicates that the element is editable.
> false, which indicates that the element is not editable.
>
> If the attribute is given without a value, like Example Label, its value is treated as an empty string.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/contenteditable)

But funny, it's indeed not a boolean:

> Note that although its allowed values include true and false, this attribute is an enumerated one and not a Boolean one.

If we read [the specs about *boolean attributes*](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/common-microsyntaxes.html#boolean-attribute)

> 2.3.2 Boolean attributes
>
> A number of attributes are boolean attributes. The presence of a boolean attribute on an element represents the true value, and the absence of the attribute represents the false value.
>
> If the attribute is present, its value must either be the empty string or a value that is an ASCII case-insensitive match for the attribute's canonical name, with no leading or trailing whitespace.
>
> The values "true" and "false" are not allowed on boolean attributes. To represent a false value, the attribute has to be omitted altogether.

`hidden` is an boolean attribute and `hidden="true"` isn't valid!

I will take a step back to explain this with a few examples:

> Can you explain a bit on the the inherit state, which is the missing value default statement? In my case, when it's missing, how is it inheriting a =true when my parent doesn't have any contenteditable attribute?

There a 3 states with the `contenteditable` attribute:

- true, these examples will make the content editable

  ```html
  <div contenteditable="true"></div>
  <div contenteditable=""></div>
  <div contenteditable></div>
  ```
- false, the content is not editable:

  ```html
  <div contenteditable="false"></div>
  ```
- inherited: it's inherited when the attribute is not defined or invalid value. For example: the content of  `<p>` is here editable in this example:

  ```html
  <div contenteditable> foo
    <p>bar</p>
  </div>
  ```

  the same for this case, as the `<p>` inherits from `<div>`, as it value is invalid.

  ```html
  <div contenteditable> foo
     <p contenteditable="wrong">bar</p>
  </div>
  ```

  and in this case, the content `foo` is editable and `bar` is not, there is not inherit here:

  ```html
  <div contenteditable> foo
    <p contenteditable="false">bar</p>
  </div>
  ```

See also [the specs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#attr-contenteditable):

> The contenteditable content attribute is an enumerated attribute whose keywords are the empty string, true, and false. The empty string and the true keyword map to the true state. The false keyword maps to the false state. In addition, there is a third state, the inherit state, which is the missing value default and the invalid value default.

#### CSS attribute selector

About the css question, (maybe it should be a new question on stackoverflow)

> Another thing I have noticed is that if I don't specify =true, then targeting it with CSS only works with:
> [contenteditable] and not [contenteditable="true"]

[The specs](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-3/#attribute-selectors) says:

> 6.3.1. Attribute presence and value selectors CSS2 introduced four attribute selectors:
>
> [att] Represents an element with the att
> attribute, whatever the value of the attribute.
>
> [att=val] Represents
> an element with the att attribute whose value is exactly "val".

Comment: Thanks. The last line is what confused me `Note that although its allowed values include true and false, this attribute is an enumerated one and not a Boolean one.`

Comment: Me also a bit, so double checked the specs. See edit.

Comment: Can you explain a bit on the `the inherit state, which is the missing value default` statement? In my case, when it's missing, how is it inheriting a `=true` when my parent doesn't have any `contenteditable` attribute?

Comment: updated with a few examples! Hope this makes everything clear :)

Comment: @PranoyC is my answer still unclear? I reverted your edit (revision 7) because your edit wasn't correct.

Comment: That was my mistake. You are correct. Didn't realize that an empty string was also a `true`. Honestly I don't know why they designed it this way... should have simply made it a boolean attribute based on whether it was present or not. But it seems like it was done because of this where various browsers support other experimental values too like `plaintext-only`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/contenteditable

Comment: Seeing this in 2021, I see that `element.contenteditable='true'` and `element.contenteditable=true` BOTH work and NOT because `'true'` is truthy!!!